TS Error: MyItem is assignable to the constraint of type T, but T could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint
I have a function named copyItem, which accepts a generic constrained param T.
But when it is called with another generic type,  ts emits the error as described in the title.
Function definition:
function copyItem<T extends { children: T[] }>(data: T): T {
    return data
}

Test Code:
interface MyItem {
    children: MyItem[]
}

function testCopyItem<T extends MyItem>(data: T) {
    copyItem(data)
}

Got this error:
Argument of type 'T' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ children: T[]; }'.
  Type 'MyItem' is not assignable to type '{ children: T[]; }'.
    Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
      Type 'MyItem[]' is not assignable to type 'T[]'.
        Type 'MyItem' is not assignable to type 'T'.
          'MyItem' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'MyItem'.ts(2345)

The workaround I came up with is to declare an extra generic type V, which extends T, and replace T with V in the code, demonstrated as below:
function copyItemV2<V extends T, T extends { children: T[] }>(data: V): V {
    return data
}

Test OK Now:
// ok
function testCopyItem<T extends MyItem>(data: T) {
    copyItemV2(data)
}

(The whole example can be found at TS Playground.)
What's the reason TS complains about the first one,  but accepts the second one?

T extends MyItem and T extends {children: T[]} are different constraints. (e.g., MyItem & {a: 0} meets the former not the latter.) When you call copyItem(data), TS infers it as copyItem<T>(data), and T fails to meet the constraint. Your workaround is bizarre, and only works because T has no inference site, everything falls back to its constraints, which looks sort of like {children: any[]}. Weird behavior of weird workarounds is not too illuminating. The "right" workaround is copyItem<MyItem>(data). Does that fully address the q? If so I'll write an a; if not, whats missing?
